# How do i own bounds.center components attach to this gameobject transform info?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bounds

[image: an screenshot of transform and area bounds for a gameobject]

I want to my `bounds.center` attach to this gameobject `transform.position`

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are asking. You want that your bounds center always equals your transform position?

Comment: yes, you are right,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to make sure that the center of your custom bounds always matches the objects `transform.position`

On the phone right now so not sure if this way works

```
private void Update ()
{
    oriBounds.center = transform.position;
}
```

But for sure you could do

```
private void Update ()
{
    oriBounds = new Bounds(transform.position, oriBounds.size);
}
```

In order to do this also in the EditMode you could add [`[ExecuteAllways]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteAlways.html)

```
[ExecuteAllways]
public class AreaBounds : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...
}
```

So while not in `PlayMode` but in `EditMode`

> Update is (only) called when something in the Scene changed.

If you want it **only** happening in the EditMode you could additionally check

```
private void Update ()
{
    if(!Application.isPlaying)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: i try this,this is must to run my game ,but i don't want to run, im sorry my description is not clear,thanks bro,i want that my bounds center always equals  transform position,not in running time

Comment: Ah I see. Updated the answer

Comment: aha,why am i so stupid,[ExecuteAllways] hit the nail on the head ,thanks you so much, master,

Comment: @Jack If this solved your problem, vote it up and mark it as the accepted answer.